Obscure late 80's or early 90's family movie with a plot like 'Big'
I'm looking for help identifying a family movie from 80's or early 90's that I watched as a kid. The movie is very similar to Tom Hank's Big and most likely a rip-off because I believe it came out after.
The premise is about a boy that fantasizes about his teacher and wishes he was older to date her. The boy then either through an experiment or time machine becomes older and meets/dates his teacher... Due to his love for her, he tells her who he is and eventually becomes a boy again.
There were a lot of body swap movies in the 80s and 90s but besides those and Big, I haven't been able identify this movie. If anyone out there can, please let me know. Thank you.

Sounds like the late 80s comedy  14 Going on 30. It actually preceded Big by a few months, though.

14 Going on 30 is a 1988 made-for-TV movie broadcast by American Broadcasting Company and Buena Vista Television, and later distributed by Walt Disney Home Video. It stars Steven Eckholdt as Danny, a fourteen-year-old boy who is infatuated with his teacher Peggy Noble (Daphne Ashbrook). Danny uses a "growth accelerator" to make himself appear older than his actual age in an attempt to seduce her. A similar age swap and nearly identical title appears in the 2004 film 13 Going on 30, and the earlier film may have influenced the latter.

They start dating, but the teacher eventually realizes that Danny is her student and he turns 14 again. Here are the first few minutes:



EDIT: As Pesetas74 mentioned, this was actually preceded by a 1987 Italian movie called Da grande with a somewhat similar plot. 1987\1988 also saw the release of 3 other movies about young people switching bodies with older people: Like Father Like Son, 18 Again! and Vice Versa.

Fun fact. There is an italian movie, "Da grande" (could be translated as "Grown up"), whose plot is very similar to Big, that was released a few months before the movie with Tom Hanks. According to IMDB the release dates are 1987 and 1988. Here is the (very poor indeed) IMDB page: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0164519/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl. I guess it has never been established who "inspired" who and it has been regarded as a "casual, although rather odd, resemblance" case.

Fascinating. And I just now realized that 14 Going on 30 actually preceded Big... Chalk it up to the Twin Film phenomenon, I guess. I'll embellish the answer.

Actually, @Pesetas74, you might want to put this up as an answer. It's quite close to what the OP described and they never mentioned the country of origin.

A little late with this answer, but I'd like to send a very sincere thanks to those that researched this and posted it here.

The plot of the movie mentioned by the OP is very similar to the italian movie "Da Grande" (that could be translated as "Grown up"). The italian movie was released in 1987 and "Big" just a few months later in 1988.
The boy is in love with his teacher there too. Here is the scene of "Da Grande" where he is granted his wish and becomes a grown up:



Wikipedia and other internet sites I've stumbled upon claim that "Big" was inspired by "Da Grande", although the fact that their respective release date was so "close" might point out to casualty (or to the Twin Phenomenon that Walt indicated). By the way, this is also the opinion of italian critic Paolo Mereghetti which is quoted in the italian version of the Wikipedia page of "Da Grande": "a casual, although rather odd, resemblance of topics".

Added the bit with the teacher, if you don't mind. +1

Thank you very much for taking the time to post and answer my question. This was indeed the movie I was looking for.

@Nuno If this is the correct answer, though, don't forget to approve it by clicking on the check mark next to it.
